# CustomSimpleCursorAdapter, timing of the bindView android

Tags: android

I want to clear my mind about when does the bindView runs.

I've seen many solutions normally searching all the elements in youre list view,
(let's assume it's 3: 1 ImageView and 2 TextViews), and then simply applying the wanted method on each. (weather it's setText/setImageResource)

But I think that `bindView(View v...)` runs for every element you have when you set the newView for the specific row, which means the `v` is exactly your desired element!

That means the optimized solution is not `findViewById` like I mostly see, but to see where you at in a switch case scenario:

```
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor c) {
        switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.listImageViewPlace:
            ((ImageView)view).setImgResource(...);
            break;
        case R.id.tvListItemName:
            ((TextView)view).setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(PlacesDBHelper.NAME_COL)));
            break;
        case R.id.tvListDistance:
            ...
            break;
        }
    }
```

While the solution I mostly see is:

```
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor c) {
        ImageView img = ((ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imgView)).setImgResource(...);
TextView tv = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv)).setText(...);
    }
```

The last code got many blank implements for each time the `bindView` isn't on the specific view you want to set.

Did I get something wrong?

Comment: bindView is called once per list view item,  not 3 as you think

Comment: but if i have 3 view's on each item, it gets called 3 times per item isnt it?

Comment: No, you are called only once per item